# Convert a dict with array values to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary with string as keys and arrays as values, like this:

```
dic = {'x': array([[10],
       [27],
       [12],
       [132]]), 'y': array([[-39],
       [23],
       [42],
       [98]]), 'z': array([[-100],
       [-123],
       [92],
       [88.2]])}
```

How could i convert it to a pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
iter x   y   z 
0   10 -39 -100
1   27  23 -123
2   12  42   92
3   132 98  88.2
```

Tried the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dic)
```

Getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Per-column arrays must each be 1-dimensional
```

Comment: not sure where your input is coming from, but if you remove the 'array()' elements you'll get almost what you are looking for. If you also eliminate the sub lists, you'll get what you want.

```dic = {'x': [10, 27, 12, 132],
           'y': [-39, 23, 42, 98],
           'z': [-100, -123, 92, 88.2]}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dict comprehension with [`numpy.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k: np.ravel(v) for k, v in dic.items()})                  
print (df)
     x   y      z
0   10 -39 -100.0
1   27  23 -123.0
2   12  42   92.0
3  132  98   88.2
```

Or use `map`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(map(np.ravel, dic.values()), index=dic.keys()).T                
print (df)
       x     y      z
0   10.0 -39.0 -100.0
1   27.0  23.0 -123.0
2   12.0  42.0   92.0
3  132.0  98.0   88.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) the numpy arrays and pass them to the DataFrame constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack(list(dic.values())), columns=list(dic))
```

Or [`stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html), slice, then transpose:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.stack(dic.values())[...,0], index=list(dic)).T
```

output:

```
       x     y      z
0   10.0 -39.0 -100.0
1   27.0  23.0 -123.0
2   12.0  42.0   92.0
3  132.0  98.0   88.2
```